# How to include TWO XML Tags within Cdata section of XML?

Tags: xml

I have a sample XML Data shown below , right now i am able to include only one XML Data with in Cdata

Please tell me how can i include two XML tags with in the Cdata section

```
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap11env:Header></soap11env:Header>
          <soap11env:Body>
<strategy>
            <request>
 <fixmlMessage>
<![CDATA[<accountid>384</accountid>]]>
</fixmlMessage>
</request>
</strategy>
          </soap11env:Body>
        </soap11env:Envelope>
```

Thank you .

Comment: Please explain why you can't include another XML element in the CDATA? Where exactly are you having difficulties?

Comment: dont know when i tried this <soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap11env:Header></soap11env:Header>
          <soap11env:Body>
<strategy>
            <request>
 <fixmlMessage>
<![CDATA[<accountid>384</accountid><user>eq</user>]]>
</fixmlMessage>
</request>
</strategy>
          </soap11env:Body>
        </soap11env:Envelope>
It started giving me XML Parsing Error . (WstxParsingException) inside Java File

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  What reason do you have for wanting to do this at all?

Comment: This makes sense , this is a SOAP Request , and as part of this request it includes a XML Message , which later in java code this parses the XML File .

Comment: So why the CDATA? Why not just include the XML element directly in the request?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is acceptable -

```
<![CDATA[<myData><datum1>384</datum1><datum2>483</datum2></myData>]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no tags in CDATA, by definition. CDATA means "character data": by putting things in CDATA, you are explicitly saying "Anything in here that looks like a tag is not actually a tag". So what are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

@atara is correct, but did not explain what they were getting at. No matter what reason you have for adding XML in CDATA content and later extracting it and parsing it with Java, you still need valid XML to parse. The two elements you have in there, by themselves do not make valid XML, there is no root element. When taken out of the CDATA content and parsed as XML by your Java app it should complain. Try wrapping it as @atara suggested such as:

<![CDATA[<msgcontent> <accountid>384</accountid><user>eq</user></msgcontent>]]>